# What does Sun obstructing the path of liberation mean?

Tags: astrology

An Astrologer told me that I cannot get liberation in this janma because Sun is obstructing it. He said that it is on the position of my liberation. What does it mean? Is there a way out? Are these conclusions reliable?

Comment: Forget all astrology. When you surrender yourself to Guru (if no Guru, Dakshnamurthy is there as Jagad Guru), or to your deity, or to supreme Paramatma itself, he will guide you to Moksha. Astrology wont work in human life beyond certain point if one has spiritual evolution!

Comment: to your question, Sun should be in 12th position from Rasi, for Yoga siddhi is what I have also learnt!!!! But in your case, simply stating sun is onstructing means, its difficult to answer because which place is SUN in your chart, which grahas are seeing it, what dasa you have now. Only after analysing these, we can give concrete answer here. Thus, I dont think this is a proper place for answer to your question!

Comment: Sun drives your intellect. Are you applying your intelligence to solve problems that are put in Your path? Or you just hope things will become alright by just praying and blind belief.Please apply all faculties that are given as gift to you. BTW, why do you want Liberation? You don’t need to tell me. But convince yourself.

Comment: astrological positions may have an effect on your body, but liberation is based on the grace of Iswara - and Iswara is not subject to astrology. Iswara decides liberation.